# Ways to make a process survive its parent shell's exiting?

Tags: bash, daemon, background-process, nohup, disown

In order for a process to survive its parent shell's exiting, what
    necessary and sufficient conditions does the process need to meet?

1. Specifically considering signals, what signals should be ignored by
   the process or not sent to the process?

   - SIGHUP, SIGTERM?

     But `nohup`  makes a process ignore only SIGHUP, not SIGTERM? (`disown` seems to avoid the parent shell sending any signal to the
     process)
   - Terminal generated signals, such as SIGINT, SIGQUIT, SIGTSTP, SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU?

     But `disown` and `&` (background) don't disconnect a process from its controlling terminal. (`nohup` can disconnect a process
     from its controlling terminal).
2. Besides signals, are there other necessary conditions in other aspects than signals?
3. How do you make a process survive its parent shell's exiting, given the conditions above?
4. Is the task of making a process survive its parent shell's exiting same as the task of changing the parent of the process?

   In bash shell and basic utilities (e.g. coreutils), are `disown` and
   `nohup` the only two ways to  change the parent shell process of a
   process? Does the parentage change happens when the shell exits?

Comment: A dying shell shouldn't be sending any signals other than SIGHUP (disown or nohup prevent this). You could get a SIGPIPE if your stdout or stderr was a terminal, that terminal went with the shell, and you attempt output something. Ignoring SIGPIPE and SIGHUP should therefore be enough.

Comment: @PSkocik: SIGPIPE is about a pipe.  "If your stdout or stderr was a terminal, that terminal went with the shell, and you attempt output something", there is no pipe here, isn't it? How can the signal be SIGPIPE? What should the signal be? (If I am correct, SIGTTOU is for the case when the terminal still exists)

Comment: My bad. I've played with it and my processes connected to a dead terminal are not getting SIGPIPE. (SIGPIPE isn't limited to pipes though -- you get it with sockets too).